# Create a Google+ application

Tags: google-plus

I am interested in creating a Google plus application.But I come to know that Google haven't released its api yet.Then How these guys are creating Google plus applications?

1. http://startgoogleplus.com/
2. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/egmjfgoffglfaiieliagnianjiohfnhf?hl=en-US&hc=search&hcp=main

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this. http://my.syyn.cc/gpapi Couldn't find any other doc
http://point7.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/rudimentary-googleplus-api/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one looks like the only thing it does is to allow you to access the mobile version through desktop browser, so my guess is that is "faking" the the User Agent of a mobile browser to cheat Google+.

The first one, if it just imports the photos from Facebook and adds them to Google+ it may be using the Picasa api, since it's where Google+ stores the pictures.

Even if you cannot access Google+ api just yet you can use the other Google ones to "influence" what you get in Google+. Just be creative :)

Comment: what about this [Chrome app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imckfmmchkhppgooiadfpmgnemhemedm) Are they injecting dom into the google+ webpage?

Comment: looks like, is only modifying the UI. For that you don't need the Google+ api for anything, is like using Greasemonkey: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/

Answer (score 2):

The API has now been announced at: http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/09/getting-started-on-google-api.html and the official homepage is: http://developers.google.com/+/